# Sync chart with video playing?

Tags: python, matplotlib, video, charts

I have a project which shows a chart with matplotlib and I need to sync the bars showing in a certain time based on some specific frames of a video.
How to sync them in reverse, too?

Until now I created dynamic bars that change in a specific time, and just open the video with a window, but they’re not effectively synchronized.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: The answer depends _a lot_ on your tech stack, i.e., the tools you are using. You will have to at least let us know which library you are working with and how you intend to "sync in reverse"